# Coverage.py: How to append result for multiple python scripts getting called from shell script

Tags: python, bash, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am having shell script which calls multiple python code with argument. Now my requirement is to collect the report for the whole project. Any idea how to run coverage.py on whole code and generate a consolidated report. Below is a high level template of shell script which I am using. If anyone can guide how to achieve above requirements.

```
#!/bin/bash

variable=$1
/usr/bin/python python1.py $variable
something blah blah

/xyz/abc/python python2.py $someargument
```

Comment: You can't assign variables like that - there should be no spaces around the equals sign. Also, [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: This is just a template. However, agree with you and correct the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple python calls from a shell script use append option to append report after each python run.

```
#!/bin/bash

variable=$1
coverage run python1.py $variable
something blah blah

coverage run -a python2.py $someargument
```

To see the report

```
coverage report -m
```

Report:

```
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------
python1.py       97      1    99%   95
python2.py        1      0   100%
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL               98      1    99%
```